# Bash script wouldn't start service

Tags: bash, service

I'm trying to start a service via a script that I run through cron. Basically it just does this

```
/local/services/servicename status
/local/services/servicename stop
/local/services/servicename start
```

The service starts fine if I run the commands myself, but whenever I run it via the script, and I check for the service status manually, its response is always

```
Servicename Service is not running.
```

I am truly confuse right now. Any particular reason why a bash script wouldn't be able to start the services?

Comment: Where's your `servicename` program/script located ?

Comment: /local/services/servicename

Comment: Ok, you just edited the post, did your cron script use `/local/services/servicename start` or just `servicename start` ? /local/services/ would normally not be in the PATH when it is run from cron.

Comment: Does your script have any output ? Or if the service is completely silent, does it return useful error codes you can check ?

Comment: first guess is that there is an env var exported in your cmd-line environment that's not set in your `servicename` script. If you can edit your script, add `set > myscriptEnv`, then run  `set > myCmdLineEnv` from the cmd line and `diff` the 2. Good luck.

Comment: It used /local/services/servicename. Wait, why wouldn't /local/ be under PATH? I don't seem to be getting errors saying service not found.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your specific question, but definitely a useful tip for debugging cron behavior in general. Cron sends email messages to the user it runs as. If you run that in the root crontab, run the `mail` command in a terminal as root and you'll see the cron messages in your inbox. Check them by typing the message number (or `man mail` to learn how to use it).